# package-install - not match

Tags: use-package

Window 10 (64 bit), Emacs 26.1

When in `*scratch*` buffer I run:

```
M-x package-install multiple-cursors
```

I get error `No match`

[image]

But when I go to package manager I success found and install package `multiple-cursors`

[image]

So why I get error: `No match`

Also I try autocomplete. But it not found this package

[image]

Comment: Did you try auto-completing it? I.e. first typing `M-x package-insall RET`, then start typing `multiple-` and press `TAB` to see if it offers any autocomplete options.

Comment: I try. But it not found package "multiple-...". I update post. See screenshot